# Why does this act as a singleton in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Why does this act as a singleton in NodeJS, how does it work?

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

const singleton = module.exports = io;
```

In essence, if I import this file more than once, I get the first instantiated `socket.io` instance.

Comment: Is there anything else I can clarify for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are cached by node. You are returning an instance so whenever you `require` this file you are getting that same instance (`io`) each time. The line

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
```

is only ran the first time this module is required. Afterwards, any module that requires this module will only get the returned instance.

Here is the official documentation on caching: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Comment: So this part of the code `const singleton = ` doesn't really matter?

Comment: Nope not really. You can remove it and it will work the same in this example.